# Instead of calling the same function twice

Tags: php

I'm first checking if a function returns a valid result, and then, if the result is valid, I need to use that in my script. But instead of checking once, and then coming back again to the function for its result, is there a way to do it all in one go? Here, `$strVal` is the variable I need to use in an querystring later.

```
$conn = connect();

encrypt('HIs#$%.-','x');
decrypt('6507A27EB0521AFA0776F1A4F8033041','x');

//If the function returns a valid result, 
if (encrypt('Tom','x'))
{
 echo 'Success'.$strVal;//I'll use this in a querystring later.

}
else
{
 echo 'An error occurred';
}

//Encrypt string
function encrypt($strToEncrypt,$salt)
{
    global $conn;
    $elements = $conn->prepare("select hex(aes_encrypt(:what,:salt)) as encValue");
    $elements->bindParam(':what', $strToEncrypt);
    $elements->bindParam(':salt', $salt);
    $elements->execute();
    $row = $elements->fetch();
    $strVal = $row['encValue'];
    if(is_null($strVal)){return false;}else{return $strVal;}
}

//Decrypt string
function decrypt($strToDecrypt,$salt)
{
    global $conn;
    $elements = $conn->prepare("select aes_decrypt(unhex(:what),:salt) as decValue");
    $elements->bindParam(':what', $strToDecrypt);
    $elements->bindParam(':salt', $salt);
    $elements->execute();
    $row = $elements->fetch();

    if(is_null($row['decValue']))
    {echo "Null";}else{echo $row['decValue'];}
}
```

Comment: " function returns a valid result " and "if the result is valid" I don't understand your logic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do the variable assignment inside the condition:

```
/* single 'equal' operator intended */
if( $strVal = encrypt( 'Tom', 'x' ) )
{
    echo 'Success' . $strVal;
}
```

Comment: It cant be done this way. I need $strVal out so I can use it at several placed in the script.

Comment: @Norman Wait, what? I don't understand your comment, but it seems to me that this is not the question from above but a follow-up. If you need a variable at different places in your script use a global variable or some sort of registry.

Comment: @Norman there is another way for OP: `if($buffer = encrypt('Tom', 'x')){ $strVal .= $buffer; echo 'Success', $strVal; }`, still suits to answer of **feeela**.